# objective-C '$' notation

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I'm still new to objective-c I went through a code example from git hub and saw '$' notation before parameters for example:

```
titleLabel.$height = TITLE_HEIGHT;
```

can some one explain the difference between `titleLabel.$height` and `titleLabel.height`

Comment: @PaulCezanne I think that question is illustrating a different use of `$`.

Comment: Rather than us guessing why the developer was using this non-standard construct, perhaps you can share the github project and we can tell you precisely what they're doing.

Comment: @PaulCezanne thank you for the reference but it's not the same question.

Comment: Can you give a link to the project where you saw this notation?

Comment: It is from here:  https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview/blob/master/SMCalloutView.m

As far as "why?".   Not sure;  but I'm surprised that compiles directly at all.

Answer (score 0):

The property happens to include a dollar sign in its name, it has no significance.

For Example:
`@property int $height;`

Comment: there is no property by that name, titleLabel is of type UILabel*

Comment: UILabel doesn't have a property with that name, is it possible you have a category that adds $height?